# Need help on Linked list sortedInsert

Tags: java

The question wants me to write a method for my LList class, it will add a new node into the correct position assuming that the list is already in sorted order. The list I'm dealing with is a queue.

Here's my LNode class:

```
class LNode{
    private int val;
    private LNode next;
    private LNode prev;
    public LNode(int v, LNode n, LNode p){
        next = n;
        prev = p;
        val = v;
    }
    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    public LNode getNext(){
        return next;
    }
    public LNode getPrev(){
        return prev;
    }
    public void setVal(int v){
        val = v;
    }
    public void setNext(LNode n){
        next = n;
    }
    public void setPrev(LNode p){
        prev = p;
    }
}
```

Here's my LTest class:

```
public class LTest{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        LList nums = new LList();
        nums.enqueue(55);
        nums.enqueue(20);
        nums.enqueue(13);
        nums.enqueue(11);
        nums.sortedInsert(15);


        nums.display();
    }
}
```

Here's what I've tried in LList class:

```
public void sortedInsert(int v){
    LNode tmp = head;
    while(v<tmp.getVal()){
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }
    tmp.setNext(tmp.getPrev().getNext());//tmp's next is now the original LNode
    tmp.getPrev().getNext().setPrev(tmp);//the original LNode's previous is now tmp
    tmp.getPrev().setNext(tmp);//tmp's previous LNode's next is now tmp
    tmp.setVal(v);
}
```

It does not work, the output is 55,20, then 15 forever and java crashes. I'm guess it's because tmp LNode points to itself, but to me my code is not doing that. So can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my first look at your code it looks as though you do not actually create a new node  for the new value v in the sortedInsert method. I think you will need to create a new node then itereate through your LinkedList then attach the new node and not really worry about setting the value of the data because it will be captured in the new node. Kind of something like this maybe...

```
LNode newnode = new LNode();
newnode.setVal(v);

LNode tmp = head;

while(v < head.getVal())
{
   //etc...
}
```

Don't forget that if the new node is at the beginning you need to change your head variable to point to the newnode.

Comment: So tmp.getPrev().getNext() will not give me the original LNode where tmp is set to be equal to?

Comment: forgot to call you... @Matthew

Comment: From my understanding, I would say no. When you first create 'newnode' it is not attached to the LinkedList at all, just kind of sitting alone in memory by itself. Once you find where that new node called 'newnode' should be inserted, you then rearrange all the pointer correctly. Something along the lines of newnode.setPrev(tmp); newnode.setNext(tmp.getNext()); tmp.setNext(newnode); newnode.getNext().setPrev(newnode);